# Heter Iskah practical implications for a private loan

Tags: halacha, borrowing

This question is about **practical differences in receiving a loan** from a "Heter Iskah" certified bank and from not certified one, with the same term and percentage.

In other words, besides the background Halachic permission, are there any ramifications for the borrower?

Comment: I'm not sure and certainly can't source it but suspect that payment of the interest may forbidden on the latter loan. Perhaps someone can flesh this out into an answer if it's correct.

Comment: @msh210 forbidden is not practical :) Are there any differences in payments, liability, pledge etc?

Comment: I fail to understand your comment. If it's forbidden to pay the interest, that's a practical difference: one won't be paying the interest.