# Do Heter Iskah Banks have two different loan forms for Jews and non-Jews?

Tags: halacha, money

I asked previously ["Heter-iskah-practical-implications"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94642/heter-iskah-practical-implications-for-a-private-loan?noredirect=1#comment311124_94642) but didn't get an answer yet. So I ask a simpler question.

Do H"I banks in Israel (for example) have different forms and conditions for Jews and non-Jews or the H"I is just a "Kashrus stamp" for the bank and has no practical implications on the forms?

Comment: Off-topic about Jews, not Judaism? Clearly there is no Halachik need for them to use a Heter Iska for non-Jews, so it sounds like you're just asking about bank policy.

Comment: @Salmononius2 According to the Talmud, a Jew is generally not allowed to charge interest to a gentile, as well.

Comment: @Loewian Really? I have never heard that. Can you please bring a source?

Comment: @sal  Mishneh Torah, Creditor and Debtor 5:2: "אָסְרוּ חֲכָמִים שֶׁיִּהְיֶה יִשְׂרָאֵל מַלְוֶה אֶת הָעַכּוּ''ם בְּרִבִּית קְצוּצָה אֶלָּא בִּכְדֵי חַיָּיו"  based on Bava Metzia 70b: מרבה הונו בנשך ותרבית לחונן דלים יקבצנו מאי לחונן דלים אמר רב כגון שבור מלכא אמר רב נחמן אמר לי הונא לא נצרכא אלא דאפילו רבית דעובד כוכבים

Comment: @Loewian I haven't looked up the topic thoroughly, but I don't believe that the Rambam holds that you can't lend with interest to a Goy. See 5:1 of your source. 5:2 also doesn't say not to lend with interest, but rather to limit the interest (for an external reason unrelated to the prohibition of interest). The conclusion of the Gemara seems to say the same thing as well (bottom of 70b, top of 71a).

Comment: @Salmononius2 There are indeed circumstances where interest may be charged - e.g. "בִּכְדֵי חַיָּיו" - in order to earn enough to live/eat.  However, the Rambam I quoted codifies, based on the gemara that, as a general rule, רִבִּית קְצוּצָה (interest) is forbidden by the rabbis.

Comment: @Salmononius2 (Ironically, the "בִּכְדֵי חַיָּיו" exception probably means nowadays that only the destitute are allowed to charge interest to gentiles.)